# Add template Variable in email template for Magento RMA in Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento2, email-templates, magento-enterprise-2, rma

I want to set the template variable in Magento RMA email template using observer or plugin. Unlike in email order (i.e. email_order_set_template_vars_before) or email shipment (i.e. email_shipment_set_template_vars_before), default Magento's RMA doesn't have custom event for passing template variable. So, anyone has idea regarding that.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom template variable in the email template for Magento RMA in Magento 2 Enterprise, you can use a plugin to modify the Magento\Rma\Model\Rma class.

Here are the steps to add a template variable in the email template for Magento RMA:

1. Create a module and define the plugin in the module's di.xml file:

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Rma\Model\Rma">
         <plugin name="add_custom_template_variable" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\RmaPlugin" />
     </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create the plugin class RmaPlugin and add the template variable in the beforeSendEmail method:

   ```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

    use Magento\Rma\Model\Rma;

    class RmaPlugin
    {
        public function beforeSendEmail(Rma $subject, $templateVars, $area, $store)
        {
            $templateVars['custom_variable'] = 'Custom Value';
            return [$templateVars, $area, $store];
        }
    }
   ```

In this example, the template variable $custom_variable is added with the value Custom Value.

3. Use the template variable in the email template for Magento RMA by adding the variable inside the curly braces:

   ```
   {{custom_variable}}
   ```

That's it! Now you can use the custom template variable in the email template for Magento RMA.

Comment: Hello Navneet, In the RMA module, there is no file like this Magento\Rma\Block\Adminhtml\Rma\View

Comment: Are you using Magento EE or CE? If you are using CE, then you must have installed a third-party module, because Magento EE has a built-in module.

Comment: I am using Magento EE only

Comment: I have updated my answer can you try with that

Comment: I have checked the core magento rma module and I don't find the function sendEmail in given plugin !!!

Comment: But still I tried your code, it doesn't work

Comment: ok wait, I am working at my local system. Let you know the exact code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144676/discussion-between-navneet-sharma-and-mitul-vadalia).

Comment: ok sure, we can continue in chat